# Adding user input to readline history

Tags: r, readline

In my code, I accept commands from the user:

```
input <- readline("prompt> ")
```

I would like these commands to be added to the readline history, so that the user can page back through them with the up and down arrows, et cetera.

Is there an `R` command or package that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
getlineandsave <- function(...){
    input <- readline('prompt>', ...)

    # load current history
    file1 <- tempfile("Rrawhist")
    savehistory(file1)

    # append new command to history
    cat(input, '\n', file=file1)
    loadhistory(file1)
    unlink(file1)
    return(input)
}

history() # load history before line
getlineandsave() # this will create a `readline` prompt
"this is a test line to enter at prompt"

history() # check history after line entered
```

Here, you're creating a function to wrap `readline` that saves the current history to file, appends whatever the user entered to that file and then reloads history from that saved file.

Comment: It's good but it's a bit brutal in terms of disk access. Is there any way to talk to the readline mechanism without talking to the disk?

Comment: @dash2 Not as far as I know. `savehistory` doesn't seem to work with text connections. And, as I understand it, that would be slower than the current solution anyway.

Comment: btw I think `cat()` should have an `append=TRUE` there.